# Mapping a dataframe based on the columns from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, merge

I have two `DataFrames`. One looks like this:

```
df1.head()
#CHR    Start   End Name
chr1    141474  173862  SAP
chr1    745489  753092  ARB
chr1    762988  794826  SAS
chr1    1634175 1669127 ETH
chr1    2281853 2284259 BRB
```

And the second `DataFrame` looks as follows:

```
df2.head()
#chr    start   end
chr1    141477  173860
chr1    745500  753000
chr16   56228385    56229180
chr11   101785507   101786117
chr7    101961796   101962267
```

I am looking to map the first three columns from two `DataFrames` and create a new `DataFrame`, `df3`. For example, if `#chr` from both `df1` and `df2` are equal, then look for `df2.start >= df1.start` and `df2.end <= df1.end`.

If this is the case, print it out as the following:

```
df3.head()

#chr    start   end Name
chr1    141477  173860  SAP
chr1    745500  753000  ARB
```

So far I have tried to create a function for doing this:

```
def start_smaller_than_end(df1,df2):
    if df1.CHR == df2.CHR:
        df2.start >= df1.Start
        df2.End <= df2.End

    return df3
```

However, when I run it I get the following error:

```
df3(df1, df2)
name 'df3' is not defined
```

Any suggestions and help are greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on='#CHR', right_on='#chr')

df = df[(df.start >= df.Start) & (df.end <= df.End)]
df = df[['#chr','start','end','Name']]
print (df)
   #chr   start     end Name
0  chr1  141477  173860  SAP
3  chr1  745500  753000  ARB
```

EDIT by comment:

Function `start_smaller_than_end`:

```
def start_smaller_than_end(df1,df2):
    df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on='#CHR', right_on='#chr')
    df = df[(df.start >= df.Start) & (df.end <= df.End)]
    df = df[['#chr','start','end','Name']]
    return df

df3 = start_smaller_than_end(df1,df2)
print (df3)
```

Comment: Thank you but both data frame is of different length, and so its throwing this error, ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare

Comment: Yes, but you need first merge it and compare in `merged` dataframe `df`. Is still problem after merge?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try on merged df , I see, it is working now. Thank you so much ..!!!

Comment: Is there a possible way to make it as a function as I defined above with your solution ?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122907/discussion-between-user1017373-and-jezrael).