# Select consecutive rows using Timedate function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am analysing meteorological data which is taken at non-standard intervals so the time/date entries are not all consecutive. The csv file has been read into a pandas dataframe using:

```
df4=pd.read_csv(datafilenew,parse_dates[1],infer_datetime_format=True,na_values=['M'])
```

I want to select chunks of data which are consecutive, for example every set of at least 5 rows which have consecutive time/date values. 
[Here is a screenshot of a section of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reYcV.png). I would want to select all the entries from 2011-09-10 from this example and then continue to scan the rest of the data and select other consecutive sets of rows.

Is there a simple way to do this as I am completely at a loss. Thanks.

Comment: Would `groupby` be what you're looking for? After grouping rows, you could drop those groups that do not contain at least 5 entries.

Comment: Please add some example of input and output format of dataframe.

Comment: I've added an image of the dataframe output as I cannot think of a way to make a simplified example.

Comment: Groupby by date and use transform size and create a mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this (assuming your dataframe is sorted):

```
m = df4.groupby([df4['TimeDate'].dt.date])['Direction'].transform('size') >= 5 # mask
df4 = df4.loc[m] # Apply mask
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = '''\
TimeDate,Direction
2010-01-05 10:00,2
2010-01-05 11:00,3
2010-01-05 12:00,4
2010-01-05 13:00,5
2010-01-05 14:00,6
2010-01-06 13:00,7'''

df4 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data1), sep=',', parse_dates=['TimeDate'])
df4[df4.groupby([df4['TimeDate'].dt.date])['Direction'].transform('size') >= 5]
print(df4)
```

---

**or** as suggested in comments, if you want to do something for each dataframe you could simply do this:

```
for ind, dfx in df4.groupby([df4['TimeDate'].dt.date]):
    if len(dfx) >= 5:
        # Apply your logic here for subdataframe with len >= 5
        print(dfx)
    else:
        # Apply logic for skipped subdataframes
        print('skip')
```

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to use your second suggestion to group the data. I was hoping to put this data into a new data frame, is there a way to do this?
Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am very new to programming

Comment: @Bethany no worries. Just try to show us or explain in detail how this new dataframe should look like.

Comment: Apologies, your first suggestion does this perfectly I must have done something wrog the first time I tried it

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252216/python-pandas-get-attributes-associated-with-consecutive-datetime?rq=1) for you answer

Otherwise you could probably use pandas `diff()` method [(see here)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)
And use pandas `where()` method [(see here)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to find the indices where the diff(timeseries) is the timedelta you are looking for