# How to join two dataframes for which 2 columns values are within a certain 2 ranges python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, intervals

I have 2 data frames

```
print(df1)
            Name df1  RT [min]  Molecular Weight  RT [min]+0.2  RT [min]-0.2     Molecular Weight + 0.2  Molecular Weight - 0.2  
0  unknow compound 1     7.590         194.04212         7.790         7.390                  194.24212               193.84212  
1  unknow compound 2     7.510         194.15000         7.710         7.310                  194.35000               193.95000 
2  unknow compound 3     7.410         194.04209         7.610         7.210                  194.24209               193.84209  
3  unknow compound 4     7.434         342.11615         7.634         7.234                  342.31615               341.91615 
4  unknow compound 5     0.756         176.03128         0.956         0.556                  176.23128               175.83128
```

and

```
print(df2)
                   Name  df2  Molecular Weight  RT [min]
0  β-D-Glucopyranuronic acid         194.04220     7.483
1              α,α-Trehalose         194.10000     7.350
2             Threonylserine         206.08970     8.258
3          Terephthalic acid         166.02595     7.465
4              Sulfuric acid          97.96714     8.909
```

I want to merge the rows from df2 to those in df1 if 2 conditions are met.

1. *RT [min]* value of df2 is in the intervale of  RT *[min]-0.2* and  *RT [min]+0.2* from df1
2. **AND**  *Molecular Weigh* the value of df2 is in the intervale of *Molecular Weight - 0.2* and *Molecular Weight + 0.2* from df1.

This means that if a row from df2 meets the conditions of two other rows from df1, the row of df1 will be duplicated.

so df3 should look

```
print(df3)
            Name df1  RT [min]+0.2  RT [min]-0.2  Molecular Weight + 0.2   Molecular Weight - 0.2                  Name  df2  Molecular Weight     RT [min]
0  unknow compound 1         7.790         7.390               194.24212                 193.84212  β-D-Glucopyranuronic acid          194.0422       7.483 
1  unknow compound 1         7.790         7.390               194.24212                 193.84212              α,α-Trehalose          194.1000       7.350  
2  unknow compound 2         7.710         7.310               194.35000                 193.95000  β-D-Glucopyranuronic acid          194.0422       7.483
3  unknow compound 3         8.310         7.910               206.30000                 205.90000             Threonylserine          206.0897       8.258 
4  unknow compound 4         7.634         7.234               342.31615                 341.91615                        NaN               NaN         NaN 
5  unknow compound 5         0.956         0.556               176.23128                 175.83128                        NaN               NaN         NaN
```

the first row in df2 meets the 2 conditions of the unknow compound 1 **and** unknow compound 2 from df1 so we have it twice in df3.

the second row in df2 meets the 2 conditions of the unknow compound 1 only.

the third row in df2 meets the 2 conditions of the unknow compound 3 only.

all the other rows do not meet any of the conditions from df1.

I tried to do it based on [How to join two data frames for which column values are within a certain range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range) the first answer

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.read_excel (r'D:\CD SandBox\df1.xlsx')
df_2 = pd.read_excel (r'D:\CD SandBox\df2.xlsx')

df2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['RT [min]-0.2'],df2['RT [min]+0.2'],closed='both')
df2['RT [min]'] = df2['RT [min]'].apply( lambda x : df2.iloc[df1.index.get_loc(x)])
```

But do not know what to do with the second line of code and receive this error:

```
df2['RT [min]'] = df2['RT [min]'].apply( lambda x : df2.iloc[df1.index.get_loc(x)])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\BCDD\Anaconda3\envs\PTSD\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4213, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2403, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<input>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\BCDD\Anaconda3\envs\PTSD\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\interval.py", line 730, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 8.258
```

EDIT: Trying using merge_asof

according to [How to join two DataFrames with multiple overlapping timestamps using an extra shared variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085136/how-to-join-two-dataframes-with-multiple-overlapping-timestamps-using-an-extra-s)

```
df2 = df2.drop(['RT [min]',  'Molecular Weight'], axis=1)
df2['RT [min]']=df2['RT [min]-0.2']
pd.merge_asof(df2[['RT [min]','Name df2']] , df1,on='RT [min]',direction ='forward',allow_exact_matches =True)

... 
   RT [min]           Name df2          Name  df1  Molecular Weight
0     0.556  unknow compound 5      α,α-Trehalose         194.10000
1     7.210  unknow compound 3      α,α-Trehalose         194.10000
2     7.234  unknow compound 4      α,α-Trehalose         194.10000
3     7.310  unknow compound 2      α,α-Trehalose         194.10000
4     7.390  unknow compound 1  Terephthalic acid         166.02595
```

gives wrong matching for the table.

Any idea\ hint will be appreciated

Comment: Check merge_asof

Comment: @ Dani Mesejo, tried to use merge_asof  added to the question. It gives the wrong output. I think because the values in both data frames are up to 5 digits after the zero and the merge is based on greater / lesser than which is too rough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

If you're using pandas 1.2.0 you can create the cartesian product of both dataframes and then check the conditions. Also, as you don't need `RT [min]` and `Molecular Weight` from `df1`, I'll assume you already removed them:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'cross', suffixes = [None,None])

#check if 'Molecular Weight' is in the interval:
mask1 = df3['Molecular Weight'].ge(df3['Molecular Weight - 0.2']) & df3['Molecular Weight'].le(df3['Molecular Weight + 0.2'])

#check if 'RT [min]' is in the interval
mask2 = df3['RT [min]'].ge(df3['RT [min]-0.2']) & df3['RT [min]'].le(df3['RT [min]+0.2'])

df3 = df3[mask1 & mask2].reset_index(drop = True)
```

**Output:**

```
df3
            Name df1  RT [min]+0.2  RT [min]-0.2  ...                   Name df2  Molecular Weight RT [min]
0  unknow compound 1          7.79          7.39  ...  β-D-Glucopyranuronic acid          194.0422    7.483
1  unknow compound 2          7.71          7.31  ...  β-D-Glucopyranuronic acid          194.0422    7.483
2  unknow compound 2          7.71          7.31  ...              α,α-Trehalose          194.1000    7.350
3  unknow compound 3          7.61          7.21  ...  β-D-Glucopyranuronic acid          194.0422    7.483
4  unknow compound 3          7.61          7.21  ...              α,α-Trehalose          194.1000    7.350
```

#### Option 2

As your data is considerably large, may you like to use a generator in order to don't load the whole resulting dataframe. Again, I'm assuming you removed `RT [min]` and `Molecular Weight` from `df1`.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

def df_iter(df1,df2):
    for row1, row2 in product(df1.values, df2.values):

        # RT [min]-0.2 <=  RT [min] <=  RT [min]+0.2
        if row1[2] <= row2[2] <= row1[1]:
            
            #Molecular Weight - 0.2 <= Molecular Weight <= Molecular Weight + 0.2
            if row1[4] <= row2[1] <= row1[3]:
                yield np.concatenate((row1,row2))

df3_rows = df_iter(df1,df2)
```

Then you can manipulate the rows:

```
for row in df3_rows:
    print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
['unknow compound 1' 7.79 7.39 194.24212 193.84212 'β-D-Glucopyranuronic acid' 194.0422 7.483]
['unknow compound 2' 7.71 7.31 194.35 193.95 'β-D-Glucopyranuronic acid' 194.0422 7.483]
['unknow compound 2' 7.71 7.31 194.35 193.95 'α,α-Trehalose' 194.1 7.35]
['unknow compound 3' 7.61 7.21 194.24209 193.84209 'β-D-Glucopyranuronic acid' 194.0422 7.483]
['unknow compound 3' 7.61 7.21 194.24209 193.84209 'α,α-Trehalose' 194.1 7.35]
```

Or create a dataframe:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = list(df3_rows),
      columns = np.concatenate((df1.columns, df2.columns)))
```

Which results in the same dataframe from Option 1.

**NOTE1:** Be careful with the indices in the conditionals from function `df_iter`, those work in **my** case.

**NOTE2:** I'm pretty sure your data doesn't match with the example `df3`.

Comment: thank you! the issue is my data is much bigger (number of rows) then the 5 rows data frame I posted, therefore doing a cartesian product might be  costly in the time aspect

Comment: @TaL you have to do an "implicit cartesian product" anyway, I mean, you have to compare all `df1` rows vs. all `df2` rows. How big are the dataframes?

Comment: The data frames are about  10,000 rows each

Comment: @TaL welp, that's a problem

Comment: Thank you for your time! option 2 workes perfects