# how to join two dataframes for which column values are within a certain range for multiple columns using pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Referring to the same question asked here [join dataframes for single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range/46526249) , Now I want to extend this for two more columns for example:

df1:

```
price_start  price_end  year_start  year_end  score
         10         50        2001      2005     20
         60        100        2001      2005     50
         10         50        2006      2010     30
```

df2:

```
Price  year
   10  2001
   70  2002
   50  2010
```

Now I want to map the score from df1 with respect to df2 values.

expected output:

```
price year score

10 2001 20

70 2002 50

50 2010 30
```

Comment: Would you add the expected output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range/46526249 , I was trying to extend this but could not do it.

Comment: Should the expected output for year 2010 with Price of 50 rather than 60 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Simple Solution for small dataset

For small dataset, you can cross join `df1` and `df2` by [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge), then filter by the conditions where the Price is within range and year is within range using [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) specifying the conditions, as follows:

```
(df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
    .query('(Price >= price_start) & (Price <= price_end) & (year >= year_start) & (year <= year_end)')
    [['Price', 'year', 'score']]
)
```

If your Pandas version is older than 1.2.0 (released in December 2020) and does not support merge with `how='cross'`, you can use:

```
(df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
    .query('(Price >= price_start) & (Price <= price_end) & (year >= year_start) & (year <= year_end)')
    [['Price', 'year', 'score']]
)
```

**Result:**

```
   Price  year  score
0     10  2001     20
4     70  2002     50
8     50  2010     30
```

#### Solution 2: Numpy Solution for large dataset

For large dataset and performance is a concern, you can use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html) (instead of cross join and filtering) to speed up the execution time:

We look for `Price` in `df2` is within price range in `df1` and `year` in `df2` is within year range in `df1`:

```
d2_P = df2.Price.values
d2_Y = df2.year.values

d1_PS = df1.price_start.values
d1_PE = df1.price_end.values
d1_YS = df1.year_start.values
d1_YE = df1.year_end.values

i, j = np.where((d2_P[:, None] >= d1_PS) & (d2_P[:, None] <= d1_PE) & (d2_Y[:, None] >= d1_YS) & (d2_Y[:, None] <= d1_YE))

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([df1.values[j], df2.values[i]]),
    columns=df1.columns.append(df2.columns)
)[['Price', 'year', 'score']]
```

**Result:**

```
   Price  year  score
0     10  2001     20
1     70  2002     50
2     50  2010     30
```

#### Performance Comparison

**Part 1: Compare for original datasets of 3 rows each:**

**Solution 1:**

```
%%timeit
(df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
    .query('(Price >= price_start) & (Price <= price_end) & (year >= year_start) & (year <= year_end)')
    [['Price', 'year', 'score']]
)

5.91 ms ± 87.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
%%timeit
d2_P = df2.Price.values
d2_Y = df2.year.values

d1_PS = df1.price_start.values
d1_PE = df1.price_end.values
d1_YS = df1.year_start.values
d1_YE = df1.year_end.values

i, j = np.where((d2_P[:, None] >= d1_PS) & (d2_P[:, None] <= d1_PE) & (d2_Y[:, None] >= d1_YS) & (d2_Y[:, None] <= d1_YE))

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([df1.values[j], df2.values[i]]),
    columns=df1.columns.append(df2.columns)
)[['Price', 'year', 'score']]

703 µs ± 9.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Benchmark summary: **5.91 ms vs 703 µs**, that is **8.4x times faster**

**Part 2: Compare for datasets with 3,000 and 30,000 rows:**

Data Setup:

```
df1a = pd.concat([df1] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
df2a = pd.concat([df2] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
```

**Solution 1:**

```
%%timeit
(df1a.merge(df2a, how='cross')
    .query('(Price >= price_start) & (Price <= price_end) & (year >= year_start) & (year <= year_end)')
    [['Price', 'year', 'score']]
)

27.5 s ± 3.24 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
%%timeit
d2_P = df2a.Price.values
d2_Y = df2a.year.values

d1_PS = df1a.price_start.values
d1_PE = df1a.price_end.values
d1_YS = df1a.year_start.values
d1_YE = df1a.year_end.values

i, j = np.where((d2_P[:, None] >= d1_PS) & (d2_P[:, None] <= d1_PE) & (d2_Y[:, None] >= d1_YS) & (d2_Y[:, None] <= d1_YE))

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([df1a.values[j], df2a.values[i]]),
    columns=df1a.columns.append(df2a.columns)
)[['Price', 'year', 'score']]

3.83 s ± 136 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Benchmark summary: **27.5 s vs 3.83 s**, that is **7.2x times faster**

Comment: thanks @SeaBean for the answer. this works fine but need optimized one because in my case one of the dataframe is very huge and cross join consumes more time.

Comment: @DevarajNadiger  I've done some research and got a solution with considerable performance boost.  Wrapping it up and doing some final testing.  Will let you know when ready. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), and is efficient for range joins as well, and is better than a naive cross join:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
# you can also install the dev version for the latest
# including the ability to use numba for faster performance
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

import janitor
import pandas as pd

(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2, 
    ('price_start', 'Price', '<='), 
    ('price_end', 'Price', '>='), 
    ('year_start', 'year', '<='), 
    ('year_end', 'year', '>='))
.loc(axis=1)['Price','year','score']
)
   Price  year  score
0     10  2001     20
1     70  2002     50
2     50  2010     30
```

With the `dev` version, you can select the columns as well:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

import janitor
import pandas as pd

(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2, 
    ('price_start', 'Price', '<='), 
    ('price_end', 'Price', '>='), 
    ('year_start', 'year', '<='), 
    ('year_end', 'year', '>='),
    use_numba = False,
    right_columns = ['Price', 'year'],
    df_columns = 'score')
)
   score  Price  year
0     20     10  2001
1     50     70  2002
2     30     50  2010
```

With the `dev` version, if you have numba installed, you can turn on `use_numba` for more performance.