# Speed up pandas merge and for loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm preprocessing data from large dataframe into multiple small numpy files according to x,y coordinates.

i.e. I have many pixelwise values saved in dataframe(P2), and I want to split it into smaller image like pieces (npy).

My steps are as follows.

1. Loop pieces of coordinates
2. Convert the piece of coordinates into a dataframe: P1
3. Merge P1 with the raw data:P2 by ["X", "Y"] in P2 as P_merge
4. Save P_merge as numpy files

However, since there are many pieces of coordinates (about 1000) and P2 is pretty large (38976147 rows * 13 columns), the code runs really slow.

I've try to run the for loop by multiprocess but I failed on too many global variables here.

I also tried to use dask. However, since I need to save into npys, it would stuck at converting dask dataframe into numpy.

What's the proper way to speed up for loop or panda merge here?
Thank you.

```
def split_2_pieces(img_coors: List[List[float]], P2, img_h, img_w, file_name):
    # Step1
    for (x, y) in img_coors:
        # Step2
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # x is a list, y is a list
        P1 = {"X": X.flatten(), "Y": Y.flatten()}
        P1 = pd.DataFrame(data=P1)
        
        # Step3
        P_merge = P1.merge(P2[["X", "Y", "value1", ...]], how="left", on=["X", "Y"]).fillna(0)
        
        # Step4
        P_merge_npy = np.array(P_merge).reshape(img_h, img_w, 13)
        np.save(Path(path, str(idx) + file_name), P_merge_npy)
```

The reason I need to meshgrid in step2 is that some datapoint does not appear in P2.

In order to save pixelwise map as npy files, I first generate x, y then meshgrid, and then fill in the data of P2 by pandas.merge according to "X", "Y".

The P2 is a dataframe: something like this.

| X | Y | Name | value | power1 | ... | power9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1071.564 | 2478.21 | u_mcuss | 0.0072 | 0.01 | ... | 0.023 |

Comment: What does your dataframe look like, can you share a couple of rows from it?

Comment: @BeRT2me Hi, I'm sorry that I could not screen shot my dataframe. I edit the P2 dataframe from scratch above.

Comment: Merging on index used to be faster, I would say try that out using X and Y as index for both P1 and P2

Answer (score 0):

According to the method by [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087496/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range-fo/69087821#69087821) Solution 2, I first extract the rows from P2 that really matters by "np.where".

By doing this, the merge step will be speeded up since P2 have left much less rows.

```
def split_2_pieces(img_coors: List[List[float]], P2, img_h, img_w, file_name):
    # Step1
    for (x, y) in img_coors:
        # Step2
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # x is a list, y is a list
        P1 = {"X": X.flatten(), "Y": Y.flatten()}
        P1 = pd.DataFrame(data=P1)
        
        # New step 
        x_min, x_max = x.min(), x.max()
        y_min, y_max = y.min(), y.max()
        df_X, df_Y = P2.X.values, P2.Y.values

        row_idx = np.where((df_X >= x_min) & (df_X <= x_max) & df_Y >= y_min) & (df_Y <= y_max))
        P2_extracted = P2.iloc[row_idx]
        
        # Step3 (Modified)
        P_merge = P1.merge(P2_extracted [["X", "Y", "value1", ...]], how="left", on=["X","Y"]).fillna(0)
    
        # Step4
        P_merge_npy = np.array(P_merge).reshape(img_h, img_w, 13)
        np.save(Path(path, str(idx) + file_name), P_merge_npy)
```

The original run time reduces from **18.7 seconds** to **1.13 seconds**!