# How can I efficiently merge these dataframes on range values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
section_headers =
   start_sect_  end_sect_
0            0         50
1          121        139
2          221        270


sentences =
    start_sent_  end_sent_
0             0         50
1            56         76
2            77         85
3            88        111
4           114        120
5           121        139
6           221        270
```

I'm trying to merge `sentences` that belongs under each `section_header`...

A sentence belongs under a section_header when its start_sent_ is greater than or equal to that of a section_header's start_sect_ and less than or equal to the next section_header's start_sect_, etc.

Given this, my desired output is:

```
merge =
        start_sent_  end_sent_     start_sect_
    0             0         50               0
    1            56         76               0
    2            77         85               0
    3            88        111               0
    4           114        120               0
    5           121        139               121
    6           221        270               221
```

I initially converted this to a dictionary and then created a new dataframe based on the conditions, but the amount of data I'm dealing with was very large and it took forever to iterate through the records.

I'm trying to devise a way to not have to iterate through these records to do a merge of the data. I tried the broadcast method here [Solution 2: Numpy Solution for large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087496/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range-fo), but since this method doesn't allow indexing of the arrays, it doesn't work. Otherwise, it works great for two other merge use cases I have.

Comment: Hmmm... it would be nice if whoever marked this down would let me know why.

Comment: Probably because the logic is unclear and the provided example seem to have inconsistencies between the input and output. Quick question: are the intervals non overlapping?

Comment: The logic was clear enough so that @rawson understood. I have corrected the desired output though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a use for [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Using `direction="backward"`, with `section_headers` as the right DF, the merge will be on the `<=` to row:

```py
pd.merge_asof(sentences, section_headers["start_sect_"],
              left_on="start_sent_", right_on="start_sect_",
              direction="backward")

#Out[]: 
#   start_sent_  end_sent_  start_sect_
#0            0         50            0
#1           56         76            0
#2           77         85            0
#3           88        111            0
#4          114        120            0
#5          121        139          121
#6          221        270          221
```

Comment: The output is different to your question's example output, which has a few different numbers that do not appear in the initial DataFrames.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the output. This solution worked perfectly (I had come up with a nasty kludge involving a cross join, so this is awesome!). I had tried `merge_asof` unsuccessfully, but was not aware of the `direction` setting.