# Efficient way to iteratively count entries between given dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

Dataframe `allocatedTimes` collects the allocated time (for a given activity) for a person identified by an ID.

```
ID: id of the person
startTime: allocated slot start datetime
endTime: allocated slot end datetime
weekday: calculated corresponding weekday
```

Dataframe `events` collects the events associated to each person/ID.

```
ID: id of the person
eventStartTime: event start datetime
eventEndTime: event end datetime
weekday: calculated corresponding weekday
```

**What I want: for each ID, count the number of events between the allocated time slots.**

The problem: each allocated time slot is recurring, i.e. each person sets a few hours a day for each day of the week, so the `allocatedTimes` dataframe collects all of those dates. Let's say PersonA has allocated five hours each Monday from 8am to 1pm, and set it as recurrent for a year. In the `allocatedTimes` dataframe we'd have all Monday Datetimes from now oct/2022 to oct/2023 as such:

```
ID           startTime             endTime                   weekday  
personA      2022-10-24 08:00:00   2022-10-24 13:00:00       Monday      
personA      2022-10-31 08:00:00   2022-10-31 13:00:00       Monday      
personA      2022-11-07 08:00:00   2022-11-07 13:00:00       Monday 
personA      ...                   ...                       ...
```

and in the `events` dataframe, we can find some events like:

```
ID           eventStartTime         eventEndTime              weekday  
personA      2022-10-24 08:15:00    2022-10-24 08:30:00       Monday      
personA      2022-10-24 09:40:00    2022-10-24 10:30:00       Monday      
personA      2022-10-31 09:15:00    2022-10-31 09:30:00       Monday 
personA      2022-10-31 10:15:00    2022-10-31 10:30:00       Monday 
personA      2022-10-31 11:15:00    2022-10-31 11:30:00       Monday 
personA      2022-11-07 11:00:00    2022-11-07 12:00:00       Monday 
personA      2022-11-07 12:15:00    2022-11-07 12:40:00       Monday 
personA      ...                   ...                       ...
```

The result I want is something like this:

```
ID           startTime             endTime                   weekday      nrEvents
personA      2022-10-24 08:00:00   2022-10-24 13:00:00       Monday       2
personA      2022-10-31 08:00:00   2022-10-31 13:00:00       Monday       3
personA      2022-11-07 08:00:00   2022-11-07 13:00:00       Monday       2
personB      ...                   ...                       ...          ...
```

---

My very straightforward attempt:

```
df = []
for id in list(allocatedTimes.ID):
    res = allocatedTimes[allocatedTimes.ID == id] 
    for index, row in res.iterrows():
        mask = (events.eventStartTime >= row.startTime) & (event.eventEndTime <= row.endTime)
        
        data = {
            'ID' : id,  
            'startTime' : row.startTime,
            'endTime' : row.endTime,
            'weekday' : row.weekday,
            'nrEvents' : len(events.loc[mask])
        }
        
        df.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

But this takes a lot of time to compute even on small subsets of those dataframes. So what I'm looking for is a more efficient way to reproduce this same result. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What about events that are partially inside, and partially outside, a certain allocated time span?

Comment: How large are your input dataframes?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem (very slow comparisons for times in a range) which was solved by using an `IntervalIndex` as in [How to join two dataframes for which column values are within a certain range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46525786/5358968).

Comment: @9769953 the out of slot events are not relevant as I'm interested in counting/evaluating how much a person's slots are filled on average. The dataframes are around 30k row long for the events and 15k for the allocatedTimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in both DataFrames, create a column with "start_date", then join both Dataframes on `id` and `start_date`.

```
res_df = pd.merge(allocatedTimes, events, how='left', on=['id', 'start_date'])
```

Now filter that DataFrame to only keep the rows where the event time is inside the allocated time's timeframe.

```
alloc_events = res_df.loc[(res_df.startTime <= res_df.eventStartTime) && (res_df.endTime >= res_df.eventEndTime)]
```

The rest is now a Groupby on `id`, `startTime` and `endTime`.

```
final_df = alloc_events.groupby(['id', 'startTime', 'endTime'], as_index=False).size()
```

I know it's not iterative, but it produces the end state. Apologies if iterative was an essential part of the question. Also, if for some reason it's only important if the event started inside the allocated time window, then only the filtering would need to be adjusted. Instead of size some kind of sum aggregation or count might also be helpful, but size should be the easiest.