# Pandas - merge data frames with keys that are approximately equal to each other

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

Consider the following problem. A data frame has a column of timestamps that we will represent as integers (we cannot necessarily use date time for this problem, so we will stick with integers). Another data frame has a column of timestamps which are matched to the first data frame, but there was some error in the measurements, meaning that measurements from the first data frame have +5 or -5 added to them in the second data frame.

We want to match up the timestamps, and if we cannot do this because it is ambiguous, we should put `nan`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"time1" : [1,2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"time2" : [1.2,4.3,2.3,7.9,2.9, 3.9]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"time1" : [1,2,3,4], "time2" : [1.2, 2.3, 2.9, np.nan]})
```

Here `df1` is the exactly measured data frame, `df2` contains measurements with noise errors of +-0.5, and `df3` is my desired output. Note that it is ambiguous as to the timestamp in `df2` that `4` should match to (it could be `3.9` or `4.3`, we cannot tell which), so there should be `np.nan` in that column.

Please note crucially that `df2` might have more measurements than `df1` does.

I have currently tried using a standard `.apply` statement with a lambda function. This takes a timestamp in `df1`, and then it brute force searches for a timestamp in `df2` which is at most +-0.5 away from the timestamp in `df1`. This works, but it is not fast enough for the amount of measurements I have in the experiment I'm working with. I need the most efficient solution possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join two dataframes for which column values are within a certain range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range)

Comment: no, thanks for checking @Mark

Answer (score 1):

Try the `merge_asof` function, note you will have to sort the data frames beforehand, let me know if this doesn't make sense:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='time1')
df2 = df2.sort_values(by='time2')

# merge_asof with a tolerance of 0.5
merged = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='time1', right_on='time2', direction='nearest', tolerance=0.5)

# replace the non-matched values with NaN
merged['time2'] = np.where(merged['time2'].isnull(), np.nan, merged['time2'])
```

Comment: This does not work, it gives an error to do with datatypes? `Function call with ambiguous argument types`. Note in my problem the time1, time2 columns are int and the tolerance is 100. I cannot convert these columns to datetimes, they need to be int.