# How to join two dataframes for which column values are within a certain range and some values do not match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, intervals

I have been reading [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range), since I am dealing with a similar situation.

However, I have a problem. In my version of `df_1`, I have timestamps which are outside of the values of the time ranges presented in `df_2`. Let's say I have an extra row

```
print df_1

  timestamp              A          B
0 2016-05-14 10:54:33    0.020228   0.026572
1 2016-05-14 10:54:34    0.057780   0.175499
2 2016-05-14 10:54:35    0.098808   0.620986
3 2016-05-14 10:54:36    0.158789   1.014819
4 2016-05-14 10:54:39    0.038129   2.384590
5 2023-11-22 10:54:39    0.000500   6.258710


print df_2

  start                end                  event    
0 2016-05-14 10:54:31  2016-05-14 10:54:33  E1
1 2016-05-14 10:54:34  2016-05-14 10:54:37  E2
2 2016-05-14 10:54:38  2016-05-14 10:54:42  E3
```

I need to know how can I modify the solution to the previous post

```
df_2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_2['start'],df_2['end'],closed='both')
df_1['event'] = df_1['timestamp'].apply(lambda x : df_2.iloc[df_2.index.get_loc(x)]['event'])
```

so that I get a null value for the fifth row, since I am getting now an error

Comment: Are you intervals always non-overlapping? contiguous?

Comment: They are suposed to be always non-overlaping

Comment: OK, I added a second option that works in this case (assuming only 1 match per row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `janitor`'s [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) that enables a left join easily and much more efficiently than using `apply`:

```
import janitor

out = df_1.conditional_join(df_2, 
                            ('timestamp', 'start', '>='),
                            ('timestamp', 'end', '<='),
                            right_columns=['event'],
                            how='left')
```

Or, if your intervals are non-overlapping and you expect a single match, using [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) and a mask:

```
tmp = pd.merge_asof(df_1[['timestamp']], df_2.sort_values(by=['start', 'end']),
                    left_on='timestamp', right_on='start')

df_1['event'] = df_1['event'] = tmp['event'].where(tmp['timestamp']
                                   .between(tmp['start'], tmp['end'],
                                            inclusive='both'))
```

Output:

```
            timestamp         A         B event
0 2016-05-14 10:54:33  0.020228  0.026572    E1
1 2016-05-14 10:54:34  0.057780  0.175499    E2
2 2016-05-14 10:54:35  0.098808  0.620986    E2
3 2016-05-14 10:54:36  0.158789  1.014819    E2
4 2016-05-14 10:54:39  0.038129  2.384590    E3
5 2023-11-22 10:54:39  0.000500  6.258710   NaN
```

Comment: The first alternative, using `janitor` gives me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`. I will try the other option

Comment: @slow_learner you need to install the module `pip install pyjanitor`. See [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyjanitor/)

Answer (score 2):

you can modify the lambda function to include error handling. Specifically, you can catch the KeyError that is raised when a timestamp does not match any interval in df_2. In such cases, you can return None or np.nan to indicate that there is no corresponding event.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Assuming df_1 and df_2 are already defined and have the correct datetime 

#Convert the start and end columns to datetime if they are not already
df_2['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['start'])
df_2['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['end'])

# Create an IntervalIndex
df_2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_2['start'], df_2['end'], 
closed='both')

# Apply a function to map each timestamp to an event or None
df_1['event'] = df_1['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: 
df_2.iloc[df_2.index.get_loc(x)]['event'] if df_2.index.contains(x) else 
np.nan)

print(df_1)
```

In this modified code, df_2.index.contains(x) checks whether the timestamp x is within any of the intervals in df_2. If it is, the corresponding event is returned. If not, np.nan is returned, indicating a null value.

This approach should handle rows in df_1 with timestamps outside the ranges in df_2 without raising an error

Comment: Have you tested the code? This doesn't work

Comment: @mozway True, the error is ''ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()''

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the answer from Mughees Syed :

```
interval_idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_2["start"], df_2["end"], closed="both")
df_1["event"] = df_1["timestamp"].map(
    lambda x: df_2["event"][interval_idx.get_loc(x)][0]
    if interval_idx.contains(x).any()
    else pd.NA
)
df_1
```

or:

```
df_1["event"] = (
    df_1["timestamp"]
    .map(lambda x: df_2["event"][interval_idx.contains(x)].values[:1])
    .explode()
)
```

or:

```
idx=interval_idx.get_indexer(df_1["timestamp"])
to_value=[df_2["event"].iloc[i] if i!=-1 else pd.NA for i in idx]
df_1["event"]=to_value
```