# Pandas, merging two dataframes where the time of a column in one dataframe is between the time in two columns of the other

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to be able to merge two data frames, the first with columns `time_1` and `time_2` (and others), and the second with a column `time_3`, say, where in general this second dataframe is longer than the first.

I would like to merge those two data frames by  where the entries a time in a column `time_3` of the second data frame are between `time_1` and `time_2`, and duplicate the entries of the row in the first dataframe for each entry in the second where `time_3` is between `time_1` and `time_2`.

For example, if the first data frame had the following format

| `time_1` | `time_2` | `dummy_data` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 04:02:00 | 2023-10-01 08:29:00 | -245.669907 |
| 2023-10-01 04:03:00 | 2023-10-01 08:49:00 | -1772.948571 |
| ... | ... | ... |

and the second

| `time_3` | `dummy_data2` |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 06:21:13.238024 | -131.367901 |
| 2023-10-01 06:47:19.796628 | -236.277444 |
| 2023-10-01 07:37:06.438740 | 5.915493 |
| 2023-10-01 08:16:16.995256 | -134.032433 |
| 2023-10-01 08:33:53.081095 | -103.733212 |

Then the following output would be expected

| `time_1` | `time_2` | `dummy_data` | `time_3` | `dummy_data2` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 04:02:00 | 2023-10-01 08:29:00 | -245.669907 | 2023-10-01 06:21:13.238024 | -131.367901 |
| 2023-10-01 04:02:00 | 2023-10-01 08:29:00 | -245.669907 | 2023-10-01 06:47:19.796628 | -236.277444 |
| 2023-10-01 04:02:00 | 2023-10-01 08:29:00 | -245.669907 | 2023-10-01 07:37:06.438740 | 5.915493 |
| 2023-10-01 04:02:00 | 2023-10-01 08:29:00 | -245.669907 | 2023-10-01 08:16:16.995256 | -134.032433 |
| 2023-10-01 04:03:00 | 2023-10-01 08:49:00 | -1772.948571 | 2023-10-01 06:21:13.238024 | -131.367901 |
| 2023-10-01 04:03:00 | 2023-10-01 08:49:00 | -1772.948571 | 2023-10-01 06:47:19.796628 | -236.277444 |
| 2023-10-01 04:03:00 | 2023-10-01 08:49:00 | -1772.948571 | 2023-10-01 07:37:06.438740 | 5.915493 |
| 2023-10-01 04:03:00 | 2023-10-01 08:49:00 | -1772.948571 | 2023-10-01 08:16:16.995256 | -134.032433 |
| 2023-10-01 04:03:00 | 2023-10-01 08:49:00 | -1772.948571 | 2023-10-01 08:33:53.081095 | -103.733212 |

I can make this work by "cheating" and iterating through each row and the list and then joining everything back up later as shown in the code below -- but I'm wondering if I there's a more "pandas-y" way to do this that doesn't require the nested loops and dictionary of indexes?

```py
# Load the data
df =pd.read_csv("datetime_list.csv")
df['time_3'] = pd.to_datetime(datetime_list['time_3'])

df2 = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')


indexes = {}
# Record which indexes of `df` are between which indexes of `df2`    

for i in df2.index:
    s = df2['time_3'].between(df.loc[i]['time_1'], 
                              df.loc[i]['time_2'],
                              inclusive = 'left' )
    
    friends = list(s[s == True].index)
    indexes[i] = friends
    

output_df = pd.DataFrame()
# Merge them all together, duplicating rows in df where necessary 
for key in indexes.keys():
    for idx in indexes[key]:
        output_df = output_df.append(pd.concat([df.loc[key], 
                                                df2.loc[idx]]), 
                                     ignore_index = True)
output_df
```

As you might expect, this solution is very slow. Any advice w.r.t how to do this more efficiently would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range) ?

Answer (score 2):

numpy broadcasting is what you are looking for. It's many times faster than looping too.

The advantage of this solution is you can increase the complexity of the join condition without needing to increase the complexity of the code much. Conditions like: `time3` must be between `time1` and `time2`, and another attribute must match but another attribute must differ, etc. can be easily expressed via numpy broadcasting.

```py
# For this to work, the indices on both dataframe must be
# unique. You can use .reset_index(drop=True) if you don't
# care about existing indices.
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index()

# Prepare the data for numpy broadcasting
t1 = df1["time_1"].to_numpy()[:, None]
t2 = df1["time_2"].to_numpy()[:, None]
t3 = df2["time_3"].to_numpy()

# This is the broadcasting, i.e. compare every value in t1
# against every value in t3, then every value in t3 against
# every value in t2. The result is an n * m matrix.
#
# .nonzero() will return the coordinates of cells that are True.
#   - the x coordinate is the row number in df1
#   - the y coordinate is the row number in df2
x, y = ((t1 < t3) & (t3 < t2)).nonzero()

# Then it's just a matter of combining rows at the returned
# coordinates
result = pd.concat(
    [
        df1.iloc[x].reset_index(drop=True),
        df2.iloc[y].reset_index(drop=True),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Note that if `df1` and `df2` have many rows, this has the potential to blow your computer memory as it must perform and store `n * m` comparisons.

Comment: Broadcasting is inefficient for large datasets, it will eat up all the memory and have a O(n*m) complexity. Better use other methods (see duplicate). I like janitor's `conditional_join`.

Comment: There are ways to reduce the memory footprint, such as chunking over one of the frames. Does `conditional_join` perform fewer than n*m comparisons?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact implementation, but it's quite fast and memory efficient (was working when broadcasting would fail in my tests). Another pandas-only approach is to use an IntervalIndex.