# join pandas dataframes A and B where dataframeA[colA] between dataframeB[colB] and dataframeB[colC]

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to join two pandas dataframes, where the first has records with a timestamp, and the second has date ranges (captured in two columns, FromDate and ToDate) and some metadata associated with the range.

In sql I would write it as:

```sql
select df1.*, df2.*
from df1, df2
where df1.timestamp >= df2.fromdate
and df1.timestamp <= df2.todate
```

I have tried pandasql and sqlite, but I have not been able to get access to those libraries at work.

Is there a way to join like this with pandas syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join two dataframes for which column values are within a certain range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range)

Comment: @Nick that answer seems to work only when the intervals in `df2` are disjoint, which is unclear from this question.

Comment: @QuangHoang probably should close as needs details then...

Comment: Kindly add more details to your question, with input and output example

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you could use pandas to perform the same task. If you do not have the pandas library installed use `pip install pandas` in your terminal.

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on=(df1['timestamp'] >= df2['FromDate']) & (df1['timestamp'] <= df2['ToDate']), right_index=True)
print(result)
```

Let me know if this works!