# Merging two dataframes based on a date between two other dates without a common column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I need to merge based on whether or not a date value fits in between two other dates. Basically, I need to perform an outer join where `B.event_date` is between `A.start_date` and `A.end_date`. It seems that merge and join always assume a common column which in this case, I do not have.

```
    A                           B
    start_date  end_date        event_date  price
0   2017-03-27  2017-04-20  0   2017-01-20  100
1   2017-01-10  2017-02-01  1   2017-01-27  200

Result 
    start_date  end_date        event_date  price
0   2017-03-27  2017-04-20  
1   2017-01-10  2017-02-01      2017-01-20  100
2   2017-01-10  2017-02-01      2017-01-27  200
```

Comment: Will events ever overlap in table A?

Comment: No. The time series are distinct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range

Comment: Solutions for larger databases can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others/42796283.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create data and format to datetimes:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'start_date':['2017-03-27','2017-01-10'],'end_date':['2017-04-20','2017-02-01']})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'event_date':['2017-01-20','2017-01-27'],'price':[100,200]})

df_A['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A.end_date)
df_A['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A.start_date)
df_B['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_B.event_date)
```

Create keys to do a cross join:

***New in pandas 1.2.0+*** `how='cross'` instead of assigning psuedo keys:

```
df_merge = df_A.merge(df_B, how='cross')
```

Else, with pandas < 1.2.0 use psuedo key to merge on 'key'

```
df_A = df_A.assign(key=1)
df_B = df_B.assign(key=1)
df_merge = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, on='key').drop('key',axis=1)
```

Filter out records that do not meet criteria of event dates between start and end dates:

```
df_merge = df_merge.query('event_date >= start_date and event_date <= end_date')
```

Join back to original date range table and drop key column

```
df_out = df_A.merge(df_merge, on=['start_date','end_date'], how='left').fillna('').drop('key', axis=1)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
              end_date           start_date           event_date price
0  2017-04-20 00:00:00  2017-03-27 00:00:00                           
1  2017-02-01 00:00:00  2017-01-10 00:00:00  2017-01-20 00:00:00   100
2  2017-02-01 00:00:00  2017-01-10 00:00:00  2017-01-27 00:00:00   200
```

Comment: This is a great solution -- just what I needed. I can't up-vote it since I  don't  seem to have enough "reputation" points.  Works great though.

Comment: No this method will cause an explosuon of records due to the cartesian product caused by this join.

Comment: @ScottBoston do you propose a better alternative? there doesn't seem to be a proper way to express this operation in pandas.

Comment: @pablete See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601120/6361531) as a possible solution.

Comment: great solution ! Just wndering, if with time any better efficient solutions have come up ? even the `numpy` based solution you refer to is in a way bursting out. Any new ideas?

Comment: @joel.wilson No, I haven't had any new ideas on doing this merge/join.

Comment: This solution does not work on large datasets. It will blow it out of proportion.

Comment: @Starbucks Yes, it cause a cartesian explosion in records as noted in [this comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593554/merging-two-dataframes-based-on-a-date-between-two-other-dates-without-a-common/43594038?noredirect=1#comment83325689_43594038).

Comment: For future readers, I have added an answer for larger dataframe use cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54986850/3545273)

Answer (score 1):

[conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.conditional_join.html#janitor.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) handles inequality joins efficiently, and also handles overlaps:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
```

Reusing @scottboston's data :

```py
df_B.conditional_join(
        df_A, 
        ('event_date', 'start_date', '>='), 
        ('event_date', 'end_date', '<='), 
        how = 'right'
    )

        left             right
  event_date  price start_date   end_date
0        NaT    NaN 2017-03-27 2017-04-20
1 2017-01-20  100.0 2017-01-10 2017-02-01
2 2017-01-27  200.0 2017-01-10 2017-02-01
```

Under the hood, it uses binary search, which is more efficient than a Cartesian join.
Note that if the intervals do not overlap, `pd.IntervalIndex` is another efficient solution.