# Pandas Merge on Timestamp in Time Window function

Tags: python, pandas

My question is regarding two Pandas Dataframes with timestamp information - my left dataframe has a static timestamp, and right dataframe has a time 'window' with a start and end time. I'd like to 'left' merge these dataframes on the basis of the left timestamp falling between the start and end values in the right time window. `pd.merge_asof()` gets me most of the way there if I was directly comparing two timestamps - however, my time window values and durations vary.

This would be a simplified representation of the columns in question after the goal merge:

```
timestamp_left       start_right          end_right 
2014-08-30 18:00:00  2014-08-30 15:00:00  2014-08-31 03:00:00
2017-03-31 15:30:00  nan                  nan
```

Writing this expression is pretty simple, but I can't seem to find any information in the `pandas` docs on how to call a function in a merge.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Found a solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593554/merging-two-dataframes-based-on-a-date-between-two-other-dates-without-a-common). This cartesian product method and subquery works because of my fairly small dataframe dimensions of [8000x30] and [50x5]. However, for larger datasets, and more complex problems, it would be really useful to merge on the basis of a function call returning boolean instead of testing for equality.