# I have two datafram A and B,both have one column timestamp. How I will check timestamp of A if exist in B between timestamp and (timestamp + 15 min)

Tags: python

I have two datafram A and B,both have one column timestamp.
How I will check timestamp of A if exist in B between timestamp and (timestamp + 15 min)

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593554/merging-two-dataframes-based-on-a-date-between-two-other-dates-without-a-common/43594038

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.