# Find range that point falls into?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe, `tests`, of individual tests in some boreholes:

```
  borehole  depthTest
0      B-1        1.5
1      B-1       20.0
2     B-42        1.0
3     B-42        2.0
4     B-42       15.0
5     B-42       30.0
6     B-09        1.0
7     B-09       10.0
8     B-09       15.0
```

I have another dataframe, `liths`, with ranges of lithologies of each borehole:

```
  borehole  depthTop   lith
0      B-1         0   sand
1      B-1         5   clay
2      B-1        18  shale
3     B-42         0   sand
4     B-42         1   clay
5     B-42        26  shale
6     B-09         0   sand
7     B-09        12  shale
```

The lithologies are a continuous sequence for each borehole. For example: in B-1 there is sand from a depth of 0 to 5 m, clay from 5 to 18 m, and shale from 18 m onwards. The bottom of each lithology is the top of the next. In other words, the bottom of each lithology would be `liths.groupby('borehole').depthTop.shift(-1)`

**Edit:** I want to join the two dfs so I can get the lithology of each test: I want to match on the `borehole` and then find the `lith` that has the closest `depthTop` <= `depthTest`.

For example: In B-42 there is clay from a depth of 1 m to 26 m. The test in B-42 at 15.0 m should be classified as clay because 15 is between 1 and 26.

Here's the desired result:

```
  borehole  depthTest   lith
0      B-1        1.5   sand
1      B-1       20.0  shale
2     B-42        1.0   clay
3     B-42        2.0   clay
4     B-42       15.0   clay
5     B-42       30.0  shale
6     B-09        1.0   sand
7     B-09       10.0   sand
8     B-09       15.0  shale
```

This seems like a `groupby` and `merge_asof` problem, but I can't figure out how to get them together.

My solution so far, which works, is to dump this into `sqlite3` and then do a `between` join (like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others/42796283#42796283)), but that really seems like defeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
tests['lith'] = tests.groupby('borehole')['depthTest'].transform(lambda x: pd.cut(x,
       bins = liths.loc[liths.borehole == x.name,'depthTop'].values.tolist() + [np.inf],
       labels=liths.loc[liths.borehole == x.name,'lith'], right=False))
```

Output:

```
  borehole  depthTest   lith
0      B-1        1.5   sand
1      B-1       20.0  shale
2     B-42        1.0   clay
3     B-42        2.0   clay
4     B-42       15.0   clay
5     B-42       30.0  shale
6     B-09        1.0   sand
7     B-09       10.0   sand
8     B-09       15.0  shale
```

Let's use `pd.cut` to label values in a range.
And by using groupby to get the appropriate `bins` and `labels` for `pd.cut` from liths dataframe by borehole.

Answer (score 1):

Find the closest value on `df2` and categorize:

```
def logic(k):
    vals = df2.loc[df2.borehole == k.borehole,:]
    return vals[vals.depthTop == max(vals[vals.depthTop <= k.depthTest].depthTop)].lith.item()

df.transform(logic, 1)


0     sand
1    shale
2     clay
3     clay
4     clay
5    shale
6     sand
7     sand
8    shale
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at that so closely. The expected output is correct. My description is poor. I want to match on the borehole and then find the `lith` that has `depthTop` <= `depthTest`.

Comment: In B-42 there is clay from a depth of 1 m to 26 m. The test in B-42 at 15.0 m should be classified as clay because 15 is between 1 and 26.

Comment: Then why is `7     B-09       10.0  shale` if there should be `sand` from 0 to 12? @ChuHo

Comment: You're right! I screwed that one up. Edit forthcoming.