# pandas: join dataframes based on time interval

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame with a datetime column every 10 minutes and a numerical value:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time' : pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=20, freq='10min'), 'value' : np.random.randint(2, 20, size=20)})
```

And another with a schedule of events, with a start time and end time. There can be multiple events happening at the same time:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'start_time' : ['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:00','2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 02:00:00' ], 'end_time' : ['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 02:00:00','2018-01-01 02:00:00', '2018-01-01 02:00:00', '2018-01-01 03:00:00'], 'event' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'] })
df2[['start_time', 'end_time']] = df2.iloc[:,0:2].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

I want to do a left join on df1, with all events that fall inside the start and end times. My output table should be:

```
                  time  value event
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00      5     A
1  2018-01-01 00:00:00      5     B
2  2018-01-01 00:10:00     15     A
3  2018-01-01 00:10:00     15     B
4  2018-01-01 00:20:00     16     A
5  2018-01-01 00:20:00     16     B
.....
17 2018-01-01 02:50:00      7     F
```

I attempted [these SO solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range), but they fail because of duplicate time intervals.

Comment: I don't understand where you get `value=5` from for the first two.

Comment: @user3483203 `value` is set as a random number, so the result is an example.

Comment: Ah, should have read first, thanks :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Setup*** (Only using a few entries from `df1` for brevity):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time' : pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=20, freq='10min'), 'value' : np.random.randint(2, 20, size=20)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'start_time' : ['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:00','2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 02:00:00' ], 'end_time' : ['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 02:00:00','2018-01-01 02:00:00', '2018-01-01 02:00:00', '2018-01-01 03:00:00'], 'event' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'] })

df1 = df1.sample(5)
df2[['start_time', 'end_time']] = df2.iloc[:,0:2].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

You can use a couple of straightfoward list comprehensions to achieve your result.  This answer assumes that all date columns are in fact, of type `datetime` in your DataFrame:

***Step 1***
Find all events that occur within a particular time range using a list comprehension and simple interval checking:

```
packed = list(zip(df2.start_time, df2.end_time, df2.event))
df1['event'] = [[ev for strt, end, ev in packed if strt <= el <= end] for el in df1.time]

                  time  value      event
2  2018-01-01 00:20:00      8     [A, B]
14 2018-01-01 02:20:00     14        [F]
8  2018-01-01 01:20:00      6  [C, D, E]
19 2018-01-01 03:10:00     16         []
4  2018-01-01 00:40:00      7     [A, B]
```

***Step 2***:

Finally, explode each list from the last result to a new row using another list comprehension:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[t, val, e] for t, val, event in zip(df1.time, df1.value, df1.event)
    for e in event
    ], columns=df1.columns
)
```

Output:

```
                 time  value event
0 2018-01-01 00:20:00      8     A
1 2018-01-01 00:20:00      8     B
2 2018-01-01 02:20:00     14     F
3 2018-01-01 01:20:00      6     C
4 2018-01-01 01:20:00      6     D
5 2018-01-01 01:20:00      6     E
6 2018-01-01 00:40:00      7     A
7 2018-01-01 00:40:00      7     B
```

Comment: This works well for the example dataframes provided. Do you see a way to abstract it if I have more columns in `df1` that I want to preserve in the final output?

Comment: You should just be able to add them to the columns you `zip`  in Step 2.  You could track them in a list and just inverse zip that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure of your question, but if you are trying to join on "events that fall inside the start and end times," then sounds like you need something akin to a "between" operator from SQL. You're data doesn't make it particularly clear.

Pandas doesn't have this natively, but Pandasql does. It allows you to run sqlite against you're dataframe. I think something like this is what you need:

```
import pandasql as ps

sqlcode = '''
select *
from df1
inner join df2 on df1.event=df2.event
where df2.time >= d1.start_time and df2.fdate <= d1.stop_time
'''

newdf = ps.sqldf(sqlcode,locals())
```

Relevant Question:
[Merge pandas dataframes where one value is between two others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others)

Comment: `df1` does not have `event`.

Comment: That looks very convenient. What is pandasql doing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

One option is with the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

out = df1.conditional_join(
            df2, 
           ('time', 'start_time', '>='), 
           ('time', 'end_time', '<=')
        )

out.head()
                 time  value start_time            end_time event
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00     14 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 01:00:00     A
1 2018-01-01 00:00:00     14 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 01:00:00     B
2 2018-01-01 00:10:00     10 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 01:00:00     A
3 2018-01-01 00:10:00     10 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 01:00:00     B
4 2018-01-01 00:20:00     15 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 01:00:00     A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work on `df2` to create a column with all the time with a resampling `'10min'` (like in `df1`) for each event, and then use `merge`. It's a lot of manipulation so probably not the most efficient.

```
df2_manip = (df2.set_index('event').stack().reset_index().set_index(0)
                .groupby('event').resample('10T').ffill().reset_index(1))
```

and `df2_manip` looks like:

```
                        0 event     level_1
event                                      
A     2018-01-01 00:00:00     A  start_time
A     2018-01-01 00:10:00     A  start_time
A     2018-01-01 00:20:00     A  start_time
A     2018-01-01 00:30:00     A  start_time
A     2018-01-01 00:40:00     A  start_time
A     2018-01-01 00:50:00     A  start_time
A     2018-01-01 01:00:00     A    end_time
B     2018-01-01 00:00:00     B  start_time
B     2018-01-01 00:10:00     B  start_time
B     2018-01-01 00:20:00     B  start_time
B     2018-01-01 00:30:00     B  start_time
...
```

Now you can `merge`:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2_manip[[0, 'event']].rename(columns={0:'time'}))
```

and you get `df1`:

```
                  time  value event
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00      9     A
1  2018-01-01 00:00:00      9     B
2  2018-01-01 00:10:00     16     A
3  2018-01-01 00:10:00     16     B
...
33 2018-01-01 02:00:00      6     D
34 2018-01-01 02:00:00      6     E
35 2018-01-01 02:00:00      6     F
36 2018-01-01 02:10:00      2     F
37 2018-01-01 02:20:00     18     F
38 2018-01-01 02:30:00     14     F
39 2018-01-01 02:40:00      5     F
40 2018-01-01 02:50:00      3     F
41 2018-01-01 03:00:00      9     F
```