# Merging Dataframes within loop - Pandas is slow

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the function `segmentMatch` in which I am sending two dataframes. I am using a `for` loop through one dataframe and have some condition to check before I merge with another dataframe with the loop variable. It gives me perfect answer but because both dataframes were too big, it is too slow.

Is there any way I can improve the speed.

```
def segmentMatch(self, df, df_program):

    df_result = []
    for i, rview in df.iterrows():
        df_tmp = []
        df1 = []
        df_tmp = df_program.ix[(df_program.iD == rview['id']) & 
                                (rview['end_time'] >= df_program.START_TIME) &
                                (rview['start_time'] <= df_program.END_TIME)]
        df1 = rview.to_frame().transpose()
        tmp = pd.merge(df1, df_tmp,how='left')
        df_result.append(tmp)


    result = pd.concat(df_result, axis=0)
    del(df1, df_tmp, tmp)
    return result
```

Please help me. I am using Visual studio code and Python 3.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is size of both DataFrames?

Comment: Can you add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? E.g. for each DataFrame 5 rows with 3 columns?

Comment: df = 11 columns and more than 10,00,000 rows whereas df_program = 7 columns and 40000 rows

Answer (score 1):

In general the advise is to **never** loop through a dataframe if it can be avoided. Looping is super slow compare to any `merge` or `join`.

Conditional joins are not great in pandas. They are pretty easy in SQL however. A small lifehack could be to `pip install pandasql` and actually use SQL. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others). The example below is not tested.

```
import pandasql as ps

sqlcode = '''
SELECT *
FROM df
JOIN df ON 1=1 
    AND df_program.iD = df.id 
    AND df.end_time >= df_program.START_TIME
    AND df.start_time <= df_program.END_TIME
'''

new_df = ps.sqldf(sqlcode, locals())
```

If you prefer to not use `pandassql`I would suggest just merging and checking the conditions later. That of course requires a bit more memory, depending on the overlap in IDs. Again, bit tricky without data, but something along the lines of

```
full_df = df.join(df, on='id', rsuffix='program_')
filtered_df = df.loc[(df.end_time >= df.program_START_TIME) & (df.start_time <= df.program_END_TIME)
```

If it doesn't fit in memory, you could try to do the same with a [dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html) dataframe.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Read your CSVs in like this
df = dd.read_csv('')
df_program = dd.read_csv('')

# Now make sure your ids are index in both dataframes

# Join and filter like above 
full_df = df.join(df, on='id', rsuffix='program_')
filtered_df = df.loc[(df.end_time >= df.program_START_TIME) & (df.start_time <= df.program_END_TIME)

# Write the result to a CSV or convert to pandas (if it fits your memory anyway):
df = full_df.compute()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try with SQL. Is there any other way to improve my code without using SQL.

Comment: Added a suggestion - think  you can just join on the equality and filter as a second step :)

Comment: Thanks again. I have tried use join(), because it is filtering after join, it removes all the data where condition doesn't match. I want all the data from df + match data from df_program. Could you please help again.

Comment: Also, when I try to join all the records it gives me memory error as too big dataframes to join

Comment: Added another option :)