# Join two datasets in Python if datetimes are within certain time of one another, as well as create an 'unmatched' dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have two datasets:

df1 and df2, where I would like the columns to merge together from df1, if the datetimes are within 20 seconds of df2

```
df1





Connect                 Ended


4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM     4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM

3/31/2020 11:00:08 AM   3/31/2020 11:00:10 AM

4/1/2020 10:00:05 PM    4/1/2020 12:00:05 PM
```

df2

```
Start                   End


4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM     4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM

3/31/2020 11:00:10 AM   3/31/2020 11:00:14 AM
```

Desired Output:

df3

```
Match_Start1             Match_End1                     Match_Start2              Match_End2



4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM     4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM          4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM     4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM

3/31/2020 11:00:08 AM   3/31/2020 11:00:10 AM        3/31/2020 11:00:10 AM   3/31/2020 11:00:14 AM
```

df4  (unmatched)

```
Unmatched_Start         Unmatched_end  



4/1/2020 10:00:05 PM    4/1/2020 12:00:05 PM
```

Dput:

df1

```
   :
   '  Connect   Ended\n0    4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM     4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM\n1  
   3/31/2020 11:08:08 AM  3/31/2020 11:00:10 AM\n2   4/1/2020 10:00:05 PM    4/1/2020 12:00:05    PM'
```

df2

```
  Out[117]:
  '    Start    End\n0    4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM    4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM\n1     
  3/31/2020 11:08:08 AM  3/31/2020 11:00:14 AM\n2                    NaN                    NaN'
```

What I am thinking:

```
df2 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="Connect", by = "Ended", 
tolerance=pd.Timedelta('20s'), direction='backward')
```

However, how do I incorporate the condition of the 20 seconds, as well as show the unmatched dataset?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others

Comment: Hi, I do not believe this is a duplicate because I do not see the unmatched dataset. My question is also asking to link the two datasets based on if they are within 20 seconds of one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to read in the data and convert to datetime format - i read in the data with [clipboard](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) and parsed the dates there. Secondly, you need to sort the data by the key(in this case the key is 'Connect' for df1 and 'Start' for df2). after that pandas [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof) should suffice. note that the merger can only occur on one key, not multiple :

sort the dataframes

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Connect','Ended'])
df2 = df2.sort_values(['Start','End'])
```

merge the dataframes

```
merger = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,
                       left_on='Connect',
                       right_on='Start',
                       tolerance = pd.Timedelta('20s'),
                       direction='forward')

merger

     Connect                   Ended            Start              End
0   2020-03-31 11:00:08 2020-03-31 11:00:10 2020-03-31 11:00:10 2020-03-31 11:00:14
1   2020-04-01 22:00:05 2020-04-01 12:00:05        NaT             NaT
2   2020-04-06 13:15:21 2020-04-06 14:05:18 2020-04-06 13:15:21 2020-04-06 14:05:18
```

should be easy to pick the matched and unmatched rows :

```
matched = merger.dropna()
matched


         Connect              Ended                    Start         End
0   2020-03-31 11:00:08 2020-03-31 11:00:10 2020-03-31 11:00:10 2020-03-31 11:00:14
2   2020-04-06 13:15:21 2020-04-06 14:05:18 2020-04-06 13:15:21 2020-04-06 14:05:18

unmatched = merger.loc[merger.isna().any(axis=1)]
unmatched

    Connect               Ended           Start End
1   2020-04-01 22:00:05 2020-04-01 12:00:05 NaT NaT
```

hope it suffices... the docs have more examples to guide u thru if u get stomped

Comment: Ah ok thank you! I was on the right track, but got stumped along the way! Thank you!!

Comment: yes u were on the right track. we all get stomped sometimes. time to get back to work. cheers!

Comment: Hi @Sammywemmy, just wondering, the tolerance timedelta('20s') , what exactly does it mean? does it mean that these two 4/9/2020 9:40:33 AM 4/9/2020 9:52:35 AM  4/9/2020 9:40:34 AM 4/9/2020 9:52:35 AM    should match since there's only a one sec difference? because when I ran the code, these timestamps were in the 'unmatched' dataset. I was thinking the 20 second tolerance would include it. I am researching the documentation as well. Thanks

Comment: what is ur ```direction``` parameter set as ? ```forward``` ?  ```nearest``` ?

Comment: forward. Maybe this is why, perhaps it should be 'nearest' I am still learning this