# Merge two pandas dataframe using unique key and a condition

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two dataframes, the first one:

```
KEY DATE               VALUE
A   01/01/2020         1
A   05/01/2020         3
B   01/02/2020         1
C   05/02/2020         1
```

The second dataframe:

```
KEY    START_DATE     END_DATE     VALUE2
A      01/01/2020     03/01/2020   3
B      01/03/2020     06/03/2020   4
C      01/02/2020     07/02/2020   5
```

I'd like to merge these two by KEY but also with the condition that DATE from the first dataframe is included in the window START_DATE - END_DATE in the second dataframe.

Expected result:

```
KEY   DATE          START_DATE    END_DATE     VALUE     VALUE2
A     01/01/2020    01/01/2020    03/01/2020   1         3
A     05/01/2020    NAT           NAT          1         NAN
B     01/02/2020    NAT           NAT          1         NAN
C     05/02/2020    01/02/2020    07/01/2020   1         5
```

I tried this, but this method can be very memory consuming if the KEY has multiple entries in the second dataframe:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on="KEY", how="left")
idx = (df.DATE >= df.START_DATE) & (df.DATE <= df.END_DATE)
df = df[idx]
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others

Comment: What you are doing seems pretty reasonable. Check the link in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 "DATE..." columns are of *string* type, then start from
converting them to *datetime*:

```
df1.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE, dayfirst=True)
df2.START_DATE = pd.to_datetime(df2.START_DATE, dayfirst=True)
df2.END_DATE = pd.to_datetime(df2.END_DATE, dayfirst=True)
```

Then, one of possible solutions is to:

- merge both DataFrames on *A* column, for now ignoring the second
  requirement (and reorder columns),
- in rows with *DATE* outside the required range, set *NaN* in three
  columns of interest.

The code to do it is:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, on='KEY', how="left")\
    [['KEY', 'DATE', 'START_DATE', 'END_DATE', 'VALUE', 'VALUE2']]
msk = res.DATE.between(res.START_DATE, res.END_DATE)
res[['START_DATE', 'END_DATE', 'VALUE2']] = res[['START_DATE', 'END_DATE', 'VALUE2']]\
   .where(msk)
```