# Pandas: Merge two dataframes on id and matching date range within +/- certain days

Tags: python, sql, pandas

### The aim:

I want to merge two dataframes on the basis of the unique number and the date matching within +/-7 days

### The data:

**df1**

```
Number         Report         DateDone
1       some words      13/1/2021
1               more stuff      21/8/2021
44      balbla          11/4/2020
2       gobbledy bla    01/03/2019
44      rara rasputin   13/10/2021
44      tree frogs      11/10/2010
```

**df2**

```
Number         Report             DateDone
1       hocum poklum       11/1/2021
1       mjimmeny cricket   21/8/2021
44      it wasnt me        11/2/2020
2       its not really     6/03/2019
44      im innocent        12/10/2021
44      bullfrogs          11/01/2010
```

### The intended result

```
Number.df1     Report.df1   DateDone.df1     Number.df2    Report.df2     DateDone.df2
1              some words    13/1/2021              1          hocum poklum      11/1/2021
1              more stuff    21/8/2021              1          jimmeny cricket   21/8/2021
2              gobbledy bla  01/03/2019             2          its not really    6/03/2019
44             rara rasputin 13/10/2021             44         im innocent       12/10/2021
```

I was going to use a sql merge similar to one I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others) but I am having difficulty knowing how to merge on the number and a date range. Do I need to calculate the 7 days before and after the DateDone in df1? Surely there is a more efficient way than having to calculate two new columns first?

```
qry = '''
    select  
        df1.DateDone_start TermStart,
        df1.DateDone_end TermEnd,
        df2.DateDone df2Start,
        df1.Number,
        df2.Number
    from
        df1 join df2 on
        date between df1.DateDone_start and df1.DateDone_end join df1 on
        df1.Number = df2.Number
    '''
df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, conn)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `Number` and then filter using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) the condition where `DateDone.df2` is [`.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) `DateDone.df1` +/- 7 days by using +/-`pd.DateOffset(days=7)`, as follows:

```
df1['DateDone'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DateDone'], dayfirst=True)
df2['DateDone'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DateDone'], dayfirst=True)

df_merge = df1.merge(df2, on='Number', suffixes=('.df1', '.df2'))

result = df_merge.loc[
             df_merge['DateDone.df2'].between(
                 df_merge['DateDone.df1'] - pd.DateOffset(days=7), 
                 df_merge['DateDone.df1'] + pd.DateOffset(days=7))]
```

Result:

```
print(result)



    Number     Report.df1 DateDone.df1        Report.df2 DateDone.df2
0        1     some words   2021-01-13      hocum poklum   2021-01-11
3        1     more stuff   2021-08-21  mjimmeny cricket   2021-08-21
8       44  rara rasputin   2021-10-13       im innocent   2021-10-12
13       2   gobbledy bla   2019-03-01    its not really   2019-03-06
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) then filter out rows that are within 7 days:

```py
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on='Number', suffixes=('.df1', '.df2'))
new_df = new_df[
    abs(new_df['DateDone.df1'] - new_df['DateDone.df2']) <= pd.Timedelta(days=7)
    ]
```

`new_df`:

```
    Number     Report.df1 DateDone.df1        Report.df2 DateDone.df2
0        1     some words   2021-01-13      hocum poklum   2021-01-11
3        1     more stuff   2021-08-21  mjimmeny cricket   2021-08-21
8       44  rara rasputin   2021-10-13       im innocent   2021-10-12
13       2   gobbledy bla   2019-03-01   its not really    2019-03-06
```

---

Convert to 'DateDone' to DateTime for both Frames if not already done:

```py
df1['DateDone'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DateDone'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df2['DateDone'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DateDone'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Get the duration between two datetimes

```py
new_df['DateDone.df1'] - new_df['DateDone.df2']
```

```
0        2 days
1     -220 days
2      222 days
3        0 days
4       60 days
5     -549 days
6     3743 days
7      610 days
8        1 days
9     4293 days
10   -3410 days
11   -4019 days
12     273 days
13      -5 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Apply `abs` to remove directionality from durations and compare to the desired duration:

```py
abs(new_df['DateDone.df1'] - new_df['DateDone.df2']) <= pd.Timedelta(days=7)
```

Use this index to determine which rows to keep:

```
0      True
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13     True
dtype: bool
```