# Add values to a column based on conditions with range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two datasets:

`Dict`

| Number_ID | Price | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.49 | 20200101 | 20991231 |
| 2 | 0.25 | 20200101 | 20200502 |
| 2 | 0.49 | 20200503 | 20200509 |
| 3 | 0.13 | 20200401 | 20200403 |
| 3 | 0.15 | 20200404 | 20991231 |

and

`Sales_List`

| Number_ID | Date of Sale |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20200103 |
| 2 | 20200431 |
| 2 | 20200505 |
| 3 | 20200402 |
| 3 | 20200408 |

My goal is to use data from Dict table and put right value to Sales_List['Price'] from Dict['Price'] on following conditions:

```
Number_ID is the same
Sales['Date of Sales'] is between Dict['StartDate'] and Dict['EndDate']
```

I've tried following code, but i have some error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd

Sales_List['Price'] = np.where((Sales_List['Number_ID'] == Dict['Number_ID']) & 
                               (Sales_List['Date of Sale'] >= Dict['StartDate']) & 
                               (Sales_List['Date of Sale'] < Dict['EndDate']),
                               Dict['Price'],'')
```

also I have tried following code:

```
Sales_List = Sales.merge(Dict, how='left', on='Number_ID').reset_index()
Sales_List['Value'] = np.where((Sales_List['Date of Sale'] >= Dict['StartDate']) & 
                               (Sales_List['Date of Sale'] < Dict['EndDate']),1,0)
Sales_List = Sales_List[Sales_List['Value'] = 1]
```

But in the second example this merge allocates too much memory and crashed it. (Sales_List is more than 30M rows, Dict has 12k rows)

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.15 GiB for an array with shape (5, 191907116) and data type int64
```

Any of you have any idea how I can do something like that in python in more efficient way (than second example)?

Output should looks like:

| Number_ID | Date of Sale | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20200103 | 3.49 |
| 2 | 20200431 | 0.25 |
| 2 | 20200505 | 0.49 |
| 3 | 20200402 | 0.13 |
| 3 | 20200408 | 0.15 |
| 3 | 20200401 | 0.13 |
| 3 | 20200409 | 0.15 |
| 2 | 20200509 | 0.49 |
| 2 | 20200508 | 0.49 |

Comment: Pandas isn't the best choice for data of this size. Maybe Dask is more helpful to you.

Comment: @QuangHoang have you example how to do this in Dask ?

Comment: I don't use Dask. You can read [Dask's join](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-joins.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge pandas dataframes where one value is between two others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others)

Comment: @DavidKaftan this solution still takes too much memory