# Match data in dataframes

Tags: python

I want to match the information in two dataframes conditional on dates. For instance, my first dataframe has a column date:

| DATE |
| --- |
| 2022-10-01 |
| 2022-10-22 |
| 2022-11-14 |

My second dataframe (dates may not coincide with start and end of month):

| CATEGORY | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-30 |
| 2 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-31 |
| 3 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-11-30 |

The resulting dataframe should look like:

| DATE | CATEGORY | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | 2 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-30 |
| 2022-10-22 | 2 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-31 |
| 2022-11-14 | 3 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-11-30 |

Notice that DATE must be between START and END. I managed to find the result I wanted by merging the two dataframes (using other variables). However, merging generates additional rows that must be filtered afterwards, and this can be a problem if the data size is large.

Comment: You might have to get creative and generate a shared id between the two dataframes based on your desired join condition. Maybe something using a pandas date_range could work? Sorry if this doesn't help much.

Comment: Are you sure that the first row of the expected result dataframe is right (especially start and end date)?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others